# DialogFlow detectIntentText

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am using DF with Python API and here is the code and I can't use the detect intent text.

If I use the second line I get the next error:
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/newagent/agent' denied.

If I use the first one:
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Resource name 'projects/newagent/agent/environments/draft/users//agent/sessions/5276b6d4-a0b6-4e91-84d3-16512d1f3299' does not match 'projects/*/agent/environments/*/users/*/sessions/*'.

I have enabled billing on Google Cloud and the user has Owner privileges. What is going wrong?

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
session_client = dialogflow_v2.SessionsClient()

#----------------------------------------------------------Lines that I talk about in the question---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
session = "projects/newagent/agent/environments/draft/users/<user id>/sessions/6344a857-9de5-406c-ba0f-c71b7b3ffdba"
#----------------------------------------------------------Lines that I talk about in the question---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow_v2.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
    query_input = dialogflow_v2.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

detect_intent_texts("newagent/agent/environments/draft/users/<User Number>",str(uuid.uuid4()),"Que tal?","es-ES")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Session ID should have the format `projects/<Project ID>/agent/sessions/<Session ID>` (being `<Project ID>` the ID of the GCP project where your agent is located and `<Session ID>` the ID you use for your ongoing session), as can be seen in [this documentation page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent).

In your code I see that you are calling the `detect_intent_texts()` function like:

```
project_id = "newagent/agent/environments/draft/users/<User Number>"
session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
texts = "Que tal?"
language_code = "es-ES"
```

I see two main errors here:

1. The Project ID has the wrong format, it should be the ID of your GCP project, which usually has a format like `my-first-project` or similar, and slashes `/` are not supported, so you are using a wrong [Project ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects).
2. The text should be a Python list of strings, like `["hello"]` and not just `"hello"`.

Just as an example, the following minimal code provides the result below:

```
import dialogflow

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text))

detect_intent_texts("my-project","abcd",["hello"],"en-US")
```

Result:

```
user@my-project:~/dialogflow$ python detect_intent_minimal.py
Session path: projects/my-project/agent/sessions/abcd
Fulfillment text: Hi!
```

Therefore I suspect that changing the `project_id` to its correct value and the `texts` to a list should solve your issues.

---

***EDIT:***
I have been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing with a `403 PermissionDenied` message by using a Service Account without the required permissions.

In order to run intents in Dialogflow, you need to use a Service Account with one of the following roles:

[image]

*Dialogflow API Admin* and *Dialogflow API Client* can query for intents, and therefore, one of those is required in order to make the type of requests you are trying to do with your script.

I see you said that your user has owner privileges over the project. However, the issue may be that you are using a wrong service account. In order to set up authentication correctly, follow [the steps detailed in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication). In summary, you will have to create a Service Account with the right permissions, download its JSON key, and use it as an environment variable by running the command `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/your/key.json"` wherever you are running the script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation but it did not work. I have the correct Project ID, I just wrote newAgent in order to make everything easier. The full name is newAgent-bjs83. Using the code that you posted(using dialogflow or dialogflow_v2) does not fix the problem I get the following exception:

google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/newagent-b6bb7/agent' denied.

Any ideas of the reason? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Forgot to say, is in the line :
session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

Comment: What I meant when I said that you had the wrong Project ID was that you are passing as Project ID a string of the format `newagent/agent/environments...`, while it should only be `newagent`. As you can see in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes/create), the correct format is simply `projects/<Project ID>/agent/sessions/<Session ID>`. That is why I understand that the session path built was wrong. If you print it with `print(session)` it should show something like that format.

Comment: In any case, please have a look at my edit in order to see more details about how to deal with the `403 PermissionDenied` error.

Answer (score 0):

When an identity calls a Google Cloud Platform API, Google Cloud Identity and Access Management(IAM) requires that the identity has the appropriate permissions to use the resource for which you have to create custom roles and then assign to service account. Then you will use that service account to call Google Cloud Platform API. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-change-log) you can search Dialogflow and see that DF is supported with custom roles only. That is why you have google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent'. Do following steps:

1. Go to you project in Google Cloud Platform and then select roles as shown here: [image: as shown here]
2. Then click on Create Role, insert role name and related fields. Then click on Add Permissions and in the filter, search 'Service: Dialogflow'. Select the permissions you want and then click on create.
3. Then select this: [image: Then select this.]
4. Click on Create Service Account and on Select Role option, type and search for the role you created on step 2 and save the account.
5. Do this: [image: Do this]. A list of service account will show. Click on 'Create credentials' button.
6. Select the service account created in above steps and choose JSON. Then select Create. A JSON file be downloaded.
7. Add that file in your code as: `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'yourfilename.json'`
8. Create an agent in Dialogflow console with google project for which you did all of the above steps. Enjoy :D

Comment: Please, refrain from sharing Project IDs, keys and other sensitive information in your answers (including screenshots), as this can lead to security issues.